# Given $\vec{v}$, find the shortest vector $\vec{w}$ such that $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} = 5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> If $\vec{v} = (1,2)$ draw all vectors $\vec{w} = (x,y)$ in the plane  $x,y$ with $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} = x + 2y = 5$. Which is the shortest $\vec{w}$?

I draw the graphic. I *believe* is about (1,2) by looking and testing some values. However math isn't about believing. What is the proper way to think about this exercise. I'm just starting with linear algebra (self-study) so any algebraic method is great.

**Source:** Ex 1.2.26, P21, *An Introduction to Linear Algebra, 4th Ed*, by Gilbert Strang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since your vector $\vec{w}$ is only defined by it's coordinates $x$ and $y$ and since those variables are defined by $x+2y=5$ you have:

$x=5-2y$ and thus $\|\vec{w}\|^2=x^2+y^2=(5-2y)^2+y^2=25+4y^2-20y+y^2$

So:

$$\|\vec{w}\|^2=5(y^2-4y+5)=f(y)$$

Derive $f$ and you get $f'(y)=5(2y-4)=10(y-2)$. Clearly this equals $0$ when $y=2$. So your minimum norm $\vec{w}$ vector is for $y=2$ which gives you $x=5-2\times 2=1$.

So it's indeed as you thought $\vec{w}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ 2 \end{array}\right)$

Comment: (+1) Of course, there's no real need to take the derivative. Simply rewrite in vertex form as $$f(y)=5(y-2)^2+5.$$

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes, I like yours better !

Comment: Thanks. Although I didn't derive since college this is a great and simple way to solve the problem (more than the calculus-free approach that @user12477 proposed). +1

Comment: You're welcome. And well yes this is a pretty straightforward way of looking at the problem. But I find @user12477's solution quite nice (elegant).

Answer (score 6):

A calculus-free approach: the dot product formula tells us that 
$$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=|\vec{v}| |\vec{w}|\cos\theta,$$
where $|\vec{v}|$ is the length (norm) of $\vec{v}$, $|\vec{w}|$ is the length of $\vec{w}$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. Noting that $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{5}$ and using $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}=5$ gives
$$ |\vec{w}| = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\cos\theta}.$$
Can you see what value of $\theta$ will make this smallest? From there, you can figure out $\vec{w}$.

$\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}$ is positive hence $ 0 \le \theta< \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: (+1) Well, clearly $\theta=\pi$ makes it the smallest, but that's nonsense. `;-)`

Comment: Although I can see your point and thank you for that (+1) these seem like a long workaround. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We minimize the square of the norm of $w$: $x^2+y^2$ with the constraint $x+2y=5$
$$f(y)=x^2+y^2=(5-2y)^2+y^2=5y^2-20y+25$$
so 
$$f'(y)=10y-20=0\iff y=2$$
hence $w=(1,2)$

Comment: It's actually $5y^2-20y+25$ not $-10y$ ;)

Comment: @Dolma thanks for your comment.

Comment: And $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 3 \\ 2 \end{array}\right)$ doesn't have the property $x+2y=5$ ;)

Comment: @Dolma You're right I corrected the typo thanks again

Comment: Yes sorry I've seen it after my comment was posted. You're welcome

Comment: You don't need calculus. $5y^2-20y+25 = 5(y^2 - 4y + 5) = 5(y-2)^2 + 5$ which has a minimum at $y=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find the shortest vector $(x,y)$ that satisfies $x+2y=5$ is to substitute, say, $x=5-2y$, and observe that you actually want to minimize $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which is the same as minimizing $x^2+y^2=(5-2y)^2+y^2=25-20y+5y^2=5(y^2-4y+5)$.

Minimizing this is simple: $f(y) = y^2-4y+5$ is a parabola in $y$ facing up, so it has a minimum where the derivative is $0$.

$$f^\prime(y)=0$$
$$2y-4=0$$
$$y=2$$

Which you can substitute back to get $x=1$.

Comment: (1,3) will result in a greater magnitude vector than (1,2). So it can't be.

Comment: Same for you, the coefficient of $y$ is $-20$ and not $-10$.