# Geometric/Visual Solution - Shortest Vector for which Dot Product = x + 2y = 5. (Strang P21 1.2.26)

Tags: linear-algebra, visualization

Much as I referenced [this same exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364503/shortest-vector), I'm questing after an exclusively geometric solution.

> **Question:** If $\color{#0070FF}{\vec{v} = (1,2)}$ draw all vectors $\vec{w} = (x,y)$ in the plane  $x,y$ with $\color{#0070FF}{\vec{v}}\cdot\vec{w} = \color{#228B22}{x + 2y = 5}$. Which is the shortest $\vec{w}$?
>
> **Algebraic solution:** It's given that $\mathbf{v \cdot w} = \color{#228B22}{x + 2y = 5}$. Thus, $\mathbf{v}$ forsooth lies on $x + 2y = 5$. We need an upper bound on $|\mathbf{w}|$, thus apply the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. $  \mathbf{v \cdot w} \leq |\mathbf{v}| \mid\mathbf{w}| \iff \cfrac{\mathbf{v \cdot w}}{|\mathbf{v}|} \leq |\mathbf{w}| \tag{CS$\neq$}$
>
> Thus, $min \;\mathbf{w} \iff  $ (CS$\neq$) becomes an equality $\iff$ $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are collinear $\iff k\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{w}$.

$\large{1.}$ How and why is $k = 1$?

$\large{2.}$ How can I solve this question with but the following picture?
Since $\mathbf{v \cdot w} := 5,$ thus $\mathbf{v \cdot w} > 0 \iff \cos(\text{angle between $\mathbf{v}$ & $\mathbf{w}$})>0$
$ \iff \text{angle between $\mathbf{v}$ & $\mathbf{w}$} \in (0, 90^{\circ}).  $ So $\mathbf{w}$ must be right of/above $\color{magenta}{x + 2y = 0}$.

[image]

Comment: $5=v\cdot w=v\cdot kv=5k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:
$$
\mathbf{v \cdot w} = 5 \Longrightarrow 
\mathbf{v} \cdot (k\mathbf{v}) = 5 \Longrightarrow 
k \|\mathbf{v}\|^2 = 5 \Longrightarrow k=1
$$

Regarding the second question ...

By definition, we have $\mathbf{v \cdot w} = \|\mathbf{v}\| \cdot \|\mathbf{w}\| \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$.

But we know that $\mathbf{v \cdot w} = 5$, and $\|\mathbf{v}\| = \sqrt 5$, so
$$
\|\mathbf{w}\|\, \cos\theta = 5/{\sqrt 5} = \sqrt 5.
$$
Now  $\|\mathbf{w}\| \cos\theta$ is the length of the projection of $\mathbf{w}$ onto $\mathbf{v}$. So, we are looking for the shortest possible vector $\mathbf{w}$ whose projected length along $\mathbf{v}$ is $\sqrt 5$. It's obvious (I think) that the shortest vector giving the desired projected length must be parallel to $\mathbf{v}$.

In other words, if the length of $\mathbf{w}$ is to be minimized, $\mathbf{w}$ must be a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{v}$, say $\mathbf{w} = k\mathbf{v}$. $\color{green}{\bigstar}$ But $\|\mathbf{v}\| = \sqrt 5$, so, to get a projected length of $\sqrt 5$, the scalar multiplier $k$ must be 1. So $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v}$.

Alternative methodology after $\color{green}{\bigstar}$:  But  $\mathbf{w} = k\mathbf{v} \Longrightarrow \|\mathbf{w}\|\ = k\|\mathbf{v}\|$,
where $\|\mathbf{w}\|\ \geq 0 \Longrightarrow LHS \geq 0 $ as well. So for the shortest $\mathbf{w}$ such that $\mathbf{v \cdot w}  = 5$ , we must choose $k = 1$. Finally, because we already determined in the anterior paragraph $\mathbf{w} = k\mathbf{v},$ thus $ \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v}.$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you're asking. And, anyway, I don't think I can explain things any more clearly than I already have.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote: "To get the minimum projected length, it's obvious (I think) that $\mathbf{w}$ must be parallel to $\mathbf{v}$." How and why so? In my updated picture, the orange vector (NOT parallel to $\color{  #0070FF}{\mathbf{v}}$) gives the SAME projection onto $\color{  #0070FF}{\mathbf{v}}$ as the brown vector (which IS parallel to $\color{  #0070FF}{\mathbf{v}}$)?

Comment: You're right. My explanation was poorly worded. I fixed it now. As you say, the orange vector has the desired projected length. In fact, any vector whose tip lies on the green line has the right projected length. Among all those vectors, the one parallel to $\mathbf{v}$ is celarly the shortest.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you were asking, at first, because your comment has several "Math Processing Error" casualties.

Answer (score 0):

When one seeketh the vector which nigh the origin, it behests the seeker to look upon circles centered therein. When one considers such perfect shapes one finds manifest the answer which one seeks. Hither, ye must consider circles $x^2+y^2=k$ as these contain the locus of all points distance $\sqrt{k}$ from the origin. Verily, it is clear the circle which takes $\langle 1,2 \rangle$ as its radius is the smallest circle for which the line $x+2y=5$ doth reside.

Comment: Completely off topic (almost): Is there an authomatic translation engine somewhere that translates modern English into Shakespearean English? If there isn't, there should be, methinks  :-)

Comment: @bubba he asked for a geometric solution. I'm simply pointing out that if you consider concentric circles about the origin, these measure the distance from the origin by their construction. The one which hits the line first gives the shortest distance. I don't think this is off topic, although you may with good cause question my old english :). Of course, your answer is a good, vector-geometric answer, but we should remember classical geometry is all about some circles.

Comment: You misunderstood. I was saying that my comment was off topic, not that your answer was off topic. The colon was supposed to imply that. I like your answer -- both the reasoning and the language.

Comment: @bubba :) oh well, it's probably best for me to include that comment as a translation if nothing else.

Comment: Much obliged. +1 for the Old English.